# Tabulator - Fetching JSON file with ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, azure-data-factory, tabulator

I'm trying to ingest a json file that is stored in an Azure blob container, having been run through the Azure Data Factory.

I've been struggling with getting the ajax request to work, despite following the documentation and reading lots of Stack Overflow questions about it.

I have already worked through various CORS issues to get access to the json file. Now that I've fixed the CORS issues I can access the json file but I now get a Data Loading Error:

```
Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type
Expecting: array 
Received:  undefined 
Data:      undefined
```

I originally thought that the issue was with a BOM that was appended to the start of the json file, just before the json array, as I was seeing it appended before the array in the preview of the file in Chrome when it was loaded.

However, I've now manually removed the BOM and re-uploaded the file to my blob storage and I'm still getting the same error.

Below is my Tabulator code that is being loaded in an html file:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxConfig:{
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors'
    },
    ajaxURL:"https://mihndbotblob.blob.core.windows.net/mihndbot-transcripts/finalTranscripts/2019-08-07.json", //ajax URL
    index:"MessageID",
    autoResize:true,
    layout:"fitData", //layout options
    placeholder:"Awaiting Data...",
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Type", field:"Type", visible:false},
        {title:"Message ID", field:"MessageID"},
        {title:"Message Time", field:"MessageTime"},
        {title:"Channel", field:"MessageChannel"},
        {title:"Sender ID", field:"MessageSenderID"},
        {title:"Sender Name", field:"MessageSenderName"},
        {title:"Conversation ID", field:"ConversationID"},
        {title:"Message", field:"MessageText"},
        {title:"Quick Reply Display Text", field:"QuickReplyDisplayText"},
        {title:"Quick Reply Payload", field:"QuickReplyPayload"},
        {title:"QnA Questions", field:"Question"},
        {title:"Answer", field:"Answer", width:400, formatter:"textarea", variableHeight:true},
        {title:"Prompts", field:"FollowUpPrompts", mutator:promptsMutator, width:500, formatter:"textarea", variableHeight:true},
    ],

    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

        return response.data; //pass the data array into Tabulator
    },

    rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
    },
});
```

Tabulator works absolutely fine when I load the json data in manually:

```
var tableData = [
    {"Type":"trace","MessageID":"aHEeHB0t0hHr7175E07zF8kfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE71Va3wN0yJv9aBAzkOk6JMZvTBRMzBNCUjCvTRuxrAVA","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:45.342Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Symptoms","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What are the symptoms of schizophrenia?\"]","Answer":"\nThe symptoms of schizophrenia are usually classified into:\n\n* Positive symptoms – any change in behaviour or thoughts, such as hallucinations or delusions\n* Negative symptoms – a withdrawal or lack of function that you would not usually expect to see in a healthy person; for example, people with schizophrenia often appear emotionless and flat","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":150,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Related Issues\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"hLgPSyBP-cAPdKYJ-bFHUckfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE4bJsq-K4GZvHL9m6guIMtShXFRY-XoxTMdZVBLLZBGDQ","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:39.582Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Schizophrenia","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What is schizophrenia?\"]","Answer":"\nViews on schizophrenia have changed over the years. Lots of people question whether it's really a distinct condition, or actually a few different conditions that overlap. But you may still be given this diagnosis if you experience symptoms such as:\n\n* psychosis (such as hallucinations or delusions)\n\n* disorganised thinking and speech\n\n* feeling disconnected from your feelings\n\n* difficulty concentrating\n\n* wanting to avoid people\n\n* a lack of interest in things\n\n* not wanting to look after yourself.\n\nBecause psychiatric experts disagree about what schizophrenia is, some people argue that this term shouldn't be used at all. Others think the name of the condition doesn't matter, and prefer to just focus on helping you manage your symptoms and meeting your individual needs.","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":147,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Prevalence\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":148,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Causes\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":149,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Symptoms\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":150,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Related Issues\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"893qgqa3cR9","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:27.853Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"WHAT_IS_MENTAL_HEALTH","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":"Mental Health","QuickReplyPayload":"WHAT_IS_MENTAL_HEALTH","Question":"[\"What is mental health?\"]","Answer":"\nIn many ways, Mental Health is just like Physical Health: Everybody has it and we need to take care of it.\n\nGood Mental Health means being generally able to think, feel and react in the ways that you need and want to live your life. But if you go through a period of poor Mental Health you might find the ways you're frequently thinking, feeling or reacting become difficult, or even impossible, to cope with. This can feel just as bad as a physical illness, or even worse.\n\nMental Health problems affect around one in four people in any given year. They range from common problems, such as depression and anxiety, to rarer problems such as schizophrenia and bipolar disorder.","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":123,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"What Types Are There?\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"V2VFDEjUb_w3uoJwMwdHYckfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE7ufPEJdVsZzedQSKsLniMtd9-f_Ngy-mk-tNd1w3X33w","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:57.637Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Suicide","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"How common is suicide?\"]","Answer":"\nApproximately 6.7% of people have attempted suicide during their lifetime in the UK","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":195,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Get Help\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"V2VFDEjUb_w3uoJwMwdHYckfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE7ufPEJdVsZzedQSKsLniMtd9-f_Ngy-mk-tNd1w3X33w","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:57.637Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Suicide","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"How common is suicide?\"]","Answer":"\nApproximately 6.7% of people have attempted suicide during their lifetime in the UK","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":195,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Get Help\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"RLOUlqwIcO4zSY4zHgWG78kfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE7gRJSePak9st7_nIIgw3OWXLvAMm4hMXeJ5kFnlIavpQ","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:20:04.294Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Get Help","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"Help me\"]","Answer":"\nBeing in a crisis can be very frightening. If you are worried about your safety, thinking of self-harm or feeling suicidal please get some help and support ASAP.\n\nWhen you're in a criss due to Mental Health problems or struggling to deal with your NeuroDiversity it can be difficult to know what to do. Everyone is deserving of support and it's vitally important that you get some when in crisis.\n\nPlease follow this link for details of where you can get help:\n\nhttps://www.mihnd.co.uk/crisis","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":196,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Help Yourself\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"G2tRRm8FFZk","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:14.723Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"WHAT_IS_NEURODIVERSITY","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":"NeuroDiversity","QuickReplyPayload":"WHAT_IS_NEURODIVERSITY","Question":"[\"What is NeuroDiversity?\"]","Answer":"\nAt its core, NeuroDiversity advocates neurological differences to be recognised and respected in the same way other human variations are. These neurological differences are viewed as a variation of how our the human brain is wired. As such, it rejects the idea that these conditions can be cured and instead celebrates them for bringing diversity to human society and culture","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":241,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"More Info\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"hLgPSyBP-cAPdKYJ-bFHUckfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE4bJsq-K4GZvHL9m6guIMtShXFRY-XoxTMdZVBLLZBGDQ","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:39.582Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Schizophrenia","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What is schizophrenia?\"]","Answer":"\nViews on schizophrenia have changed over the years. Lots of people question whether it's really a distinct condition, or actually a few different conditions that overlap. But you may still be given this diagnosis if you experience symptoms such as:\n\n* psychosis (such as hallucinations or delusions)\n\n* disorganised thinking and speech\n\n* feeling disconnected from your feelings\n\n* difficulty concentrating\n\n* wanting to avoid people\n\n* a lack of interest in things\n\n* not wanting to look after yourself.\n\nBecause psychiatric experts disagree about what schizophrenia is, some people argue that this term shouldn't be used at all. Others think the name of the condition doesn't matter, and prefer to just focus on helping you manage your symptoms and meeting your individual needs.","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":147,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Prevalence\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":148,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Causes\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":149,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Symptoms\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":150,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Related Issues\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"G2tRRm8FFZk","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:14.723Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"WHAT_IS_NEURODIVERSITY","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":"NeuroDiversity","QuickReplyPayload":"WHAT_IS_NEURODIVERSITY","Question":"[\"What is NeuroDiversity?\"]","Answer":"\nAt its core, NeuroDiversity advocates neurological differences to be recognised and respected in the same way other human variations are. These neurological differences are viewed as a variation of how our the human brain is wired. As such, it rejects the idea that these conditions can be cured and instead celebrates them for bringing diversity to human society and culture","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":241,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"More Info\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"jQ3W8nCoefM16arb5pAgQ8kfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE4L1csZIZpXf1CKnx7YFgCGg9X-fFegS4emSdid1as21g","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:33.470Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"What Types Are There?","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What types of mental health are there?\"]","Answer":"\nThere are many different mental health problems. Some of them have similar symptoms, so you may experience the symptoms of more than one mental health problem, or be given several diagnoses at once. Or you might not have any particular diagnosis, but still be finding things very difficult. Everyone’s experience is different and can change at different times. Click below to find out more about specific types of mental health problems:","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":124,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Depression\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":130,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Anxiety\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":135,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Phobias\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":140,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Eating Disorders\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":146,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Schizophrenia\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":151,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"OCD\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":166,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Personality Disorders\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":172,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Bipolar\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":156,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Panic Disorder\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":184,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Psychosis\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"RLOUlqwIcO4zSY4zHgWG78kfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE7gRJSePak9st7_nIIgw3OWXLvAMm4hMXeJ5kFnlIavpQ","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:20:04.294Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Get Help","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"Help me\"]","Answer":"\nBeing in a crisis can be very frightening. If you are worried about your safety, thinking of self-harm or feeling suicidal please get some help and support ASAP.\n\nWhen you're in a criss due to Mental Health problems or struggling to deal with your NeuroDiversity it can be difficult to know what to do. Everyone is deserving of support and it's vitally important that you get some when in crisis.\n\nPlease follow this link for details of where you can get help:\n\nhttps://www.mihnd.co.uk/crisis","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":196,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Help Yourself\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"45tDLlo7yKuzjKgGHAOYfskfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE4iCVqhprpw8f0-sbuDSIo7IcuNITny2S9mRiVxgefD6A","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:51.300Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Related Issues","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What are related issues of depression?\"]","Answer":"\nRelated issues of depression include:","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":130,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Anxiety\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":179,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Self-Harm\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":181,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Suicide\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":172,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Bipolar\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":166,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Personality Disorder\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"aHEeHB0t0hHr7175E07zF8kfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE71Va3wN0yJv9aBAzkOk6JMZvTBRMzBNCUjCvTRuxrAVA","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:45.342Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Symptoms","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What are the symptoms of schizophrenia?\"]","Answer":"\nThe symptoms of schizophrenia are usually classified into:\n\n* Positive symptoms – any change in behaviour or thoughts, such as hallucinations or delusions\n* Negative symptoms – a withdrawal or lack of function that you would not usually expect to see in a healthy person; for example, people with schizophrenia often appear emotionless and flat","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":150,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Related Issues\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"jQ3W8nCoefM16arb5pAgQ8kfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE4L1csZIZpXf1CKnx7YFgCGg9X-fFegS4emSdid1as21g","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:33.470Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"What Types Are There?","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What types of mental health are there?\"]","Answer":"\nThere are many different mental health problems. Some of them have similar symptoms, so you may experience the symptoms of more than one mental health problem, or be given several diagnoses at once. Or you might not have any particular diagnosis, but still be finding things very difficult. Everyone’s experience is different and can change at different times. Click below to find out more about specific types of mental health problems:","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":124,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Depression\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":130,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Anxiety\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":135,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Phobias\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":140,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Eating Disorders\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":146,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Schizophrenia\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":151,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"OCD\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":166,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Personality Disorders\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":172,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Bipolar\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":156,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Panic Disorder\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":184,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Psychosis\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"45tDLlo7yKuzjKgGHAOYfskfVjGLBRMdzD_oYUEHNE4iCVqhprpw8f0-sbuDSIo7IcuNITny2S9mRiVxgefD6A","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:51.300Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"Related Issues","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What are related issues of depression?\"]","Answer":"\nRelated issues of depression include:","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":130,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Anxiety\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":179,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Self-Harm\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":181,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Suicide\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":172,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Bipolar\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":166,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Personality Disorder\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"893qgqa3cR9","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:19:27.853Z","MessageChannel":"facebook","MessageSenderID":"2826538590752448","MessageSenderName":"Sean Betts","ConversationID":"2826538590752448-530667464425015","MessageText":"WHAT_IS_MENTAL_HEALTH","MessageRecipientID":"530667464425015","QuickReplyDisplayText":"Mental Health","QuickReplyPayload":"WHAT_IS_MENTAL_HEALTH","Question":"[\"What is mental health?\"]","Answer":"\nIn many ways, Mental Health is just like Physical Health: Everybody has it and we need to take care of it.\n\nGood Mental Health means being generally able to think, feel and react in the ways that you need and want to live your life. But if you go through a period of poor Mental Health you might find the ways you're frequently thinking, feeling or reacting become difficult, or even impossible, to cope with. This can feel just as bad as a physical illness, or even worse.\n\nMental Health problems affect around one in four people in any given year. They range from common problems, such as depression and anxiety, to rarer problems such as schizophrenia and bipolar disorder.","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":123,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"What Types Are There?\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5|0000011","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:18:08.634Z","MessageChannel":"webchat","MessageSenderID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","MessageSenderName":null,"ConversationID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5","MessageText":"Causes","MessageRecipientID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What causes depression?\"]","Answer":"\nThere are several ideas about what causes depression. It can vary a lot between different people, and for some people a combination of different factors may cause their depression. Some find that they become depressed without any obvious reason.\n\nPossible causes of depression are:\n\n* Childhood experiences\n* Life events\n* Other mental health problems\n* Physical health problems\n* Genetic inheritance\n* Medication, recreational drugs and alcohol\n* Sleep, diet and exercise.","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":127,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Types\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5|0000009","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:18:03.664Z","MessageChannel":"webchat","MessageSenderID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","MessageSenderName":null,"ConversationID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5","MessageText":"Psychosis","MessageRecipientID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What is psychosis?\"]","Answer":"\nPsychosis (also called a psychotic experience or psychotic episode) is when you perceive or interpret reality in a very different way from people around you. The most common types of psychosis are:\n\n* hallucinations, such as hearing voices or having visions\n\n* delusions, such as paranoia or delusions of grandeur.\n\nPsychosis affects people in different ways. You might experience it once, have short episodes throughout your life, or live with it most of the time. It's also possible to have a psychotic experience without ever being diagnosed with a particular mental health problem.\n\nSome people have a positive experience of psychosis. You may find it comforting, or feel that it helps you understand the world or makes you more creative.","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":240,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Prevalence\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":239,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Causes\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":238,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Symptoms\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":237,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Related Issues\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5|0000003","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:17:49.494Z","MessageChannel":"webchat","MessageSenderID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","MessageSenderName":null,"ConversationID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5","MessageText":"What Is Mental Health?","MessageRecipientID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What is mental health?\"]","Answer":"\nIn many ways, Mental Health is just like Physical Health: Everybody has it and we need to take care of it.\n\nGood Mental Health means being generally able to think, feel and react in the ways that you need and want to live your life. But if you go through a period of poor Mental Health you might find the ways you're frequently thinking, feeling or reacting become difficult, or even impossible, to cope with. This can feel just as bad as a physical illness, or even worse.\n\nMental Health problems affect around one in four people in any given year. They range from common problems, such as depression and anxiety, to rarer problems such as schizophrenia and bipolar disorder.","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":123,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"What Types Are There?\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5|0000005","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:17:54.321Z","MessageChannel":"webchat","MessageSenderID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","MessageSenderName":null,"ConversationID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5","MessageText":"What Types Are There?","MessageRecipientID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What types of mental health are there?\"]","Answer":"\nThere are many different mental health problems. Some of them have similar symptoms, so you may experience the symptoms of more than one mental health problem, or be given several diagnoses at once. Or you might not have any particular diagnosis, but still be finding things very difficult. Everyone’s experience is different and can change at different times. Click below to find out more about specific types of mental health problems:","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":124,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Depression\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":130,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Anxiety\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":135,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Phobias\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":140,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Eating Disorders\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":146,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Schizophrenia\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":151,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"OCD\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":166,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Personality Disorders\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":172,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Bipolar\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":156,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Panic Disorder\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":184,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Psychosis\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5|0000007","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:17:58.780Z","MessageChannel":"webchat","MessageSenderID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","MessageSenderName":null,"ConversationID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5","MessageText":"Panic Disorder","MessageRecipientID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"What is Panic Disorder?\"]","Answer":"\nPanic disorder is an anxiety disorder where you regularly have sudden attacks of panic or fear.","FollowUpPrompts":"[{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":157,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Prevalence\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":235,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Causes\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":158,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Symptoms\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":159,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Panic Attacks\"},{\"displayOrder\":0,\"qnaId\":160,\"qna\":null,\"displayText\":\"Related Issues\"}]"}
    ,{"Type":"trace","MessageID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5|0000001","MessageTime":"2019-08-07T09:17:42.363Z","MessageChannel":"webchat","MessageSenderID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","MessageSenderName":null,"ConversationID":"L4QV73hzRzsKljnv6hDaZ8-5","MessageText":"hi","MessageRecipientID":"r_u00jwzqzyu","QuickReplyDisplayText":null,"QuickReplyPayload":null,"Question":"[\"Hi\",\"Hello\",\"Howdy\",\"Sup\",\"Whassup\",\"Yo\"]","Answer":"\nHi! How are you today?","FollowUpPrompts":"[]"}
];
```

The json file that is being returned by the ajax call is structured exactly the same as the above, as per the preview in Chrome:

[image]

I've run out of ideas of how to fix the issue I'm seeing.

Comment: can you log response.data to the console using `console.log(response.data);` I think you should return response directly instead of response.data because I can see your JSON object is not structured this way.

Comment: Exactly right; `axios` uses `.data` to grab the actual response from its `response` object, but the callback passed to `ajaxResponse` already receives the data itself as `response` param. Use `return response;` instead and it starts working instantly: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1e365wr8/

Comment: That's magic, thank you! I altered the return to just `return response;` and it's now working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you need to do something like this in your ajaxResponse function

```
 ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

        return response.data.d; //pass the data array into Tabulator
    },
```